# How to programmatically disable predictive text (with no EditText)

Tags: android

There is an Android application containing self-made input field (no `TextView` or `EditText` elements), so I have to show/hide keyboard, handle user input and show entered symbols on my own.

I need to disable predictive text mode for standard view. Unfortunately Android `View` class (android.view.View) has no function `setInputType`.

There is a probable solution. Get `InputConnection` of given view and change its properties. But I cannot find how to get and set instance of current `InputConnection`, unfortunately function `onCreateInputConnection` is not called either.

Is there any method to disable predictive text mode for standard view?

Answer (score 8):

Something I've used is below- specifically the tag "textNoSuggestions" I think would work for you!

```
<EditText android:layout_marginLeft="10px" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginRight="10px"
android:id="@+id/setupactivity_ftpsite" 
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textUri">
```

Comment: Thank you, Mike. However, the application includes neither `TextView` nor `EditView` elements.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. When you tap or have focus in an editable field the keyboard will show. Are you manually showing it with no input field that has focus? Do you have some code?

Comment: Yes. I'm using self-made input field, so have to show keyboard and handle user input on my own.

Comment: here is a place to start looking - the source code of the edittext, only I think the keyboard action happens in the parent (textview) http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView

Comment: pay attention to mInputType, i think that is the variable that might get set to textNoSuggestions, and then when it shows the keyboard it has those properties

Comment: this function i think is responsible for creating the keyboard:  @Override public InputConnection  [More ...] onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {

Comment: InputConnection ic = new EditableInputConnection(this);
outAttrs.initialSelStart = Selection.getSelectionStart(mText);
outAttrs.initialSelEnd = Selection.getSelectionEnd(mText);
outAttrs.initialCapsMode = ic.getCursorCapsMode(mInputType);
return ic;

Comment: go to this page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html and then check out what they see here "For the rare people amongst us writing their own text editors, you will need to implement onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo) to return a new instance of your own InputConnection interface allowing the IME to interact with your editor."

Answer (score 2):

Sorry here is the answer in a more concise manner!

Something similar to this:

1) show the keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm =  (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(myCustomView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

2) in myCustomView (extends view), add:

```
 InputConnection onCreateInputConnection (EditorInfo outAttrs) {
     InputConnection ic = new EditableInputConnection(this);
     outAttrs.inputType = TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS;
     outAttrs.initialCapsMode = ic.getCursorCapsMode(outAttrs.inputType); //guess on this
     return ic;
}
```

This is the overall gist of what should be done. You may want to OR outAttrs.inputType instead of set equal so it preserves the default state, or call the parent onCreateInputConnection first and then just set your outAttrs.inputType (not sure if this will work or not). This should hopefully get you pretty close to your solution.