# is there any way to turn off predictive text and auto suggest in Android through code

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

i want to enable predictive text of soft Keyboard for my app. is there any way to do so in Java/Kotlin Code?

there is a way to turn off the predictive text as shown 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295745/how-to-programmatically-disable-predictive-text-with-no-edittext/)  but i found no way to turn it on through code

Comment: can you add more detail? Did you mean some thing like AutoCompleteTextView https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: If your requirement is just to show that, should have searched for autocompleteTextView before posting in here. Otherwise, you could elaborate on your problem statement.

Comment: no i want autocomplete(Suggestions) on Keyboard itself

Comment: yes i searched but found results showing only disabling predictive text.i want to turn on keyboard suggestions via code

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code in your XML file, it will help you.

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
```